# Which shader is associated with a missing texture file?

Tags: materials

On many of my blender files I get an error about a missing texture file. Now usually I can find the mesh that uses the material because it is pinkish-purple on my screen in Viewport Shading mode. However, I also get this error and everything in the scene looks fine, no obvious missing materials.

Is there a way in Blender to know what specific material(s) are using the missing file?

Comment: maybe the material is not used and you need to purge the unused datas?

Comment: @moonboots Thanks, but I've already purged everything but the default brishes in an effort to find these silly files. This all started because my F: drive crashed. I have a 4TB exterrmnal Western Digital drive and every  so often it seems to lose its mind, lol